# Create New Variable in an data frame using values from another data frame in R

Tags: r

I have two Data sets df & df1

```
df = data.frame(Name = c('A','B','C'),
                Filter = c('D','E','F'),
                Sub_A = c(6,7,8),
                Sub_B = c(9,10,11))

df1 = data.frame(Name = c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','P','P','P','P'),
                 Filter = c('D','D','D','X','E','E','E','X','F','F','F','X','Y','Y','Y','Y'),
                 Subject = c('Sub_A','Sub_B','Sub_A','Sub_B','Sub_A','Sub_B','Sub_A','Sub_B','Sub_A','Sub_B','Sub_A','Sub_B','Sub_A','Sub_B','Sub_A','Sub_B'),
                 Marks = c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25))
```

Using the Filter against name in df dataset I want to first filter Name in df1 dataset and use values against Sub_A & Sub_B from df dataset to correct the marks in df1 dataset for Sub_A & Sub_B by creating a new variable Corrected_Marks in df1 dataset.

Output Dataset should be like

```
Ouput = data.frame(Name = c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'),
                   Filter = c('D','D','D','E','E','E','F','F','F'),
                   Subject = c('Sub_A','Sub_B','Sub_A','Sub_A','Sub_B','Sub_A','Sub_A','Sub_B','Sub_A'),
                   Marks = c(10,11,12,14,15,16,18,19,20),
                   Corrected_Marks = c(6.2,10.23,7.44,8.12,13.95,9.28,10.152,17.67,11.28))
```

Comment: Can you show the calculation to correct the marks as showed in 'Ouput'

Comment: How the values in `Corrected_Marks` was obtained? Any example for calculation?

Comment: How did you get `.62` as the values are not matching with `df` or `df1`

Comment: Sorry for the type error Corrected Marks is calculated as Multiplying Marks in df1 for each Name if Filter is present in filter variable in df. for e.g. for 1st row in df1 it would be 10 *6 =  60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation is not clear.  Perhaps we can do a join after reshaping the first data into 'long' format and then the do the calculation

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # >= 1.0.0
df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = Sub_A:Sub_B, names_to = "Subject",
           values_to = "Corrected_Marks") %>% 
    # for tidyr < 1.0.0
    # gather(Subject, Corrected_Marks, Sub_A:Sub_B) %>%
    inner_join(df1, by = c("Name", "Filter",  "Subject")) %>% 
    mutate(Corrected_Marks = Marks * Corrected_Marks)
# A tibble: 9 x 5
#  Name  Filter Subject Corrected_Marks Marks
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A     D      Sub_A                60    10
#2 A     D      Sub_A                72    12
#3 A     D      Sub_B                99    11
#4 B     E      Sub_A                98    14
#5 B     E      Sub_A               112    16
#6 B     E      Sub_B               150    15
#7 C     F      Sub_A               144    18
#8 C     F      Sub_A               160    20
#9 C     F      Sub_B               209    19
```

Comment: Sir, getting an error "could not find function "pivot_longer"". Kindly help

Comment: @AmanSaddi  Please check your `packageVersion('tidyr')` It should be `1.0.0`

Comment: only issue is that I cannot update the tidyr Package but I got your logic

Comment: @AmanSaddi  In that case, replace the `pivot_longer` with `gather(Subject, Corrected_Marks, Sub_A:Sub_B)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59249859/12158757), here is another solution with `base R`, so no further packages are needed for running the code below:

```
dfm <- merge(df,df1)
Ouput <- cbind(dfm[names(df1)],
               Corrected_Marks = apply(dfm, 1, function(x) as.numeric(x["Marks"])*as.numeric(x[x["Subject"]])))
```

such that

```
  Name Filter Subject Marks Corrected_Marks
1    A      D   Sub_A    10              60
2    A      D   Sub_B    11              99
3    A      D   Sub_A    12              72
4    B      E   Sub_A    14              98
5    B      E   Sub_B    15             150
6    B      E   Sub_A    16             112
7    C      F   Sub_A    18             144
8    C      F   Sub_B    19             209
9    C      F   Sub_A    20             160
```

Note that the element order of columns `Subject` and `Marks` in `Ouput` remains the same with that in `df1`, which is different from what looks like from the solution by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59249859/12158757)